# How can I add a variable to jenkins during the install on Amazon Linux

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, redhat, jenkins-groovy, amazon-linux-2

I have a variable that I need to add as Jenkins Environment Variable so that the $jenkins_home/init.d groovy scripts can use them. I have this variable set in the host machine(where iam installing jenkins) - Amazon linux EC2 via a .sh file in /etc/profile.d and sourceing the /etc/profile . This did not help as I am not able to access the variable from jenkins. Can anybody please help on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jenkins, you can setup the global variables using the below given groovy script. You will have to use this in a shell script that you use to provision a jenkins server. This should be executed right after install so that, jenkins can use then while running jobs.

The below given groovy script creates the environment variables one by one,
`createGlobalEnvironmentVariables('Var1','DummyValue')`

This adds a global variable with name as **Var1** and value as *DummyValue*

If you have multiple values, you can use the ones given below.
`envVars.put("Key1", "Value1)`
`envVars.put("Key2", "Value2)`

before calling `instance.save()`. We have a shell script file that has this and many other functions to install and configure jenkins in a single shot.

```
import hudson.EnvVars;
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty;
import hudson.slaves.NodeProperty;
import hudson.slaves.NodePropertyDescriptor;
import hudson.util.DescribableList;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

public createGlobalEnvironmentVariables(String key, String value){

        Jenkins instance = Jenkins.getInstance();

        DescribableList<NodeProperty<?>, NodePropertyDescriptor> globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties();
        List<EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty> envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class);

        EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null;
        EnvVars envVars = null;

        if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
            newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
            globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty);
            envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars();
        } else {
            envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars();
        }
        envVars.put(key, value)
        instance.save()
}
createGlobalEnvironmentVariables('Var1','DummyValue')
```